# Ошибка при установке secp256k1

Tags: python

Пытался установить библиотеку secp256k1, однако столкнулся со следующей ошибкой

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\other\bitgen-master\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Asynco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
\pip-install-fwtipbo7\\secp256k1_2a34eb1f2b784b88a69f97ae4d525d8f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Asynco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fwtipbo7\\secp256
k1_2a34eb1f2b784b88a69f97ae4d525d8f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setupt
ools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C
:\Users\Asynco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-73co6grx'
       cwd: C:\Users\Asynco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fwtipbo7\secp256k1_2a34eb1f2b784b88a69f97ae4d525d8f\
  Complete output (1 lines):
  'pkg-config' is required to install this package. Please see the README for details.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/41/bb668a6e4192303542d2d90c3b38d564af3c17c61bd7d4039af4f29405fe/secp256k1-0.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=82c06712
d69ef945220c8b53c1a0d424c2ff6a1f64aee609030df79ad8383397 (from https://pypi.org/simple/secp256k1/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info C
heck the logs for full command output.
```

В чем может быть проблема? В гугле не нашел ответа

Comment: Ну вроде бы в тексте ошибки достаточно ясно написано, что `'pkg-config' is required to install this package.`

Comment: После этого вбиваем всего один запрос в гугл и сразу же попадаем сюда: [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922)

Comment: @andreymal я его установил и в ошибке видел это. Даже с этой библиотекой ничего не поставилось

Comment: Не забыли добавить папку, в которую установлен pkg-config, в переменную окружения PATH, чтобы команда стала доступна?